# How to fix "buttons not running php code"

Tags: php, forms, sql-update

I wrote a shortcode to insert data to database i got this code, but it ain't working the if(isset) wont even run.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
     $idedit = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
     $komentator1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['komentator1']);    

     $insert1 = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE zapasy SET komentator1 = '$komentator1' WHERE id = '$idedit'") or die(mysqli_errno($conn). '-'. mysqli_error($conn));

if($insert1)
        {
            header('Location: nominace.php?insert=success');
        } else {
            header('Location: nominace.php?insert=error');
        }
}
```

this is form i took it from

```
    <form method="POST">
             <select name="komentator1" id="komentator1" required>
                     <option value="">---</option>
                         <?php 
                        foreach($queryusers as $users) { ?>
 <option value="<?=$users['firstname']?> <?=$users['lastname']?>"><?=$users['firstname']?> <?=$users['lastname']?></option>
         <?
   </select>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$zapasytb['id']?>">
         <input type="button" name="submit1" value="Potvrdit">
          </form>
```

i am not really sure why it won't trigger the script...

Comment: second code is missing <?php } ?> for some reason it display only <?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, you need to make button type `submit`

Change

```
<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Potvrdit">
```

To:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Potvrdit">
```

input type `button` does not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
type="button"
```

To,

```
type="submit"
```

The standard button type won't submit the form. As per the documentation:

> `button`: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

and for `submit`:

> `submit`: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

**Reading Material**

[`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score 0):

Your input type should be of type **`submit`**:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Potvrdit">
```